# Should you use a backend with a headless CMS?

Tags: node.js, server, content-management-system, backend, headless

Im building a website in school and we need to use a headless CMS to manage the website when it's finished. Im using react on the front end.

My question is can i use a backend server like node js with a headless CMS or would that be unnecessary / not make sense? Im learning node and graphql in school atm and wanted to implement that to this website, could i do that alongside with a headless CMS?

Tanks for answers!

Answer (score -1):

Yes, using NextJS for example. This adds a serverside part to your application.

Answer (score -2):

Depends whether you're building headless cms yourself or just using available options like [Strapi](https://strapi.io) or others.

Comment: No, it really doesn't.